# PHP SoapClient can not handle redirect to https

Tags: php, soap, https, soap-client

I'm implementing a SOAP client with PHP SoapClient.

The wsdl-file specifies URL for a function of type http (like http://api.example.com/a/b).

However, when called, I get a response

```
HTTP/1.0 301 Moved Permanently
Location: https://api...
```

Apparently the SoapClient can not handle the redirect.

How can I solve the issue?

Comment: have you tried using a https url to begin with?

Comment: Do you get any errors or warnings? And how do you define your `SoapClient`?

Comment: @RamRaider, of course not, the url is defined in the wsdl

Comment: @simon, no errors. new SoapClient($wsdlUrl, array('soap_version' => SOAP_1_2, 'trace' => true, 'connection_timeout' => 60));

Comment: I guess you have already enabled OpenSSL?

Comment: @simon, correct, OpenSSL is enabled.

Comment: Hmm, then I don't know, sorry

Comment: @TeroLahtinen did you solve the problem?

Answer (score -1):

```
$param = array('user' => 'Gopal',
    'password' => 'Rathod',
    'KeyCode' => 'XYXXYGOPALASDADXXX',
    'ExternalID' => 'PUBLICSTORAGE',
    'sXml' => $strinXML, 'trace' => TRUE);

$soapClient = new SoapClient('https://wsdlfullUrl.asmx?WSDL', array('trace' => TRUE));
$result = $soapClient->__soapCall('Request', array($param));

echo '<br> 3. Call Request:<br>' .  $soapClient->__getLastRequest() ;
echo '<br> 4. RESPONSE:<br>' . $soapClient->__getLastResponse();


More link  http://php.net/manual/en/book.soap.php
```

Comment: Yes, this is how one uses the SoapClient, but you are not really answering the question